# Reactivity conundrum in shiny; dynamically translating text going into selectInput()

Tags: internationalization, shiny-reactivity

I am working on a multilingual shiny app using the `shiny.i18n` package to translate different parts of the UI. It works really well until I tried to dynamically translate the text inside a specific `selectInput` menu. Some reproducible code below:

```
# Translating text of a menu item from data

library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)
library(tidyverse)

# Create translation file and save in a directory called trans
system("mkdir trans")
translation_key <- data.frame(es = c("Cambiar de lenguaje", "Seleccione un proyecto", "Todos"),
                              en = c("Change language", "Select a project", "All")
                              )
write.csv(translation_key, "trans/translation_key.csv",
          row.names = FALSE, 
          quote = FALSE)

# Create data object
data <- data.frame(project_name =c("Todos","proj1", "proj2"),
                   n = c(20,30,40)
                   )
# Setup translator
trans <- Translator$new(translation_csvs_path = "trans")
trans$set_translation_language("es")


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  usei18n(trans),
  

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Reactivity test"),
        
        mainPanel(
          selectInput('selected_language',
                      trans$t("Cambiar de lenguaje"),
                      choices = trans$get_languages()
                    ),
          selectInput("project_name",
                      trans$t("Seleccione un proyecto"),
                      choices = NULL
          ),
          textOutput("n")
          )
)



# server part
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  
# update languae  
   observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
     
     update_lang(session, input$selected_language)
     print(paste("Language change!", input$selected_language))
   })
  
# change the first element of data$project and translate it! It does not do it! 
  data_rv <- eventReactive(input$selected_language, {
    
    data$project_name[1] <- trans$t("Todos")
    data
    
    
  })
  
  # update the selection for project name depending on the language
  observeEvent(data_rv(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "project_name", 
                      choices = unique(data_rv()$project_name))
  })
  
  # print the n associated with project_name selected
  output$n <- renderText({
    req(input$project_name)
    res <- data_rv() %>% filter(project_name == input$project_name)
    res$n
  })
}
    
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I attempt the translation of the first element of `data$project_name` inside an `eventReactive` call that returns the modified translated object. The problem is that the translation does not happen until after the menu for **project_name** is rendered (see screenshot below).
[image: Reactivity test app]

The application starts by default in Spanish (es) and when changed to English (en), everything is translated except the first item in the **Select a project** menu (it should say *All* instead of *Todos*).

I have found a solution using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` but the application I am working on has a very complex layout of panels and tabs and I rather not rework all the code if I can help it. Can someone recommend a workaround that works from the browser side. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative in this case could be making `data_rv` a reactive expression with a `req()` instead of an `eventReactive`. It may also keep it simple for your purpose.

I tried it like this with your example:

```r
  # change the first element of data$project and translate it! 
  data_rv <- reactive({
    req(input$selected_language)
    data$project_name[1] <- trans$t(data$project_name[1])
    data
    
  })
```

Seems it checks out!
[reactivity question image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRdrt.png)

Note: I translated reactivity test to prueba de reactividad for clarity but is not in the original reproducible example